# How to see if nock is matching the request or not?

Tags: nock

How to see if nock is matching the request or not? Is there a way one can log information on console regarding nock is matching or not to the requests being made?

Answer (score 18):

The `log` function is no more available on newer versions of nock e.g. v13.0.0 but you can set the `DEBUG` environment variable to `nock.*` as described here https://github.com/nock/nock#debugging to log each step of the matching process. For example:

```
export DEBUG=nock.* && yarn test
```

if you're using yarn to run your tests.

Comment: I would recommend the following single command if you plan on going back and forth from showing debug output to hiding it: `DEBUG=nock.* yarn test` (or `npm test` or whatever). That way the debug output goes away if you remove the first part.

Answer (score 8):

It is very simple.
Just add `.log(console.log)` to your nock object!

```
nock('https://github.com')
.log(console.log)
.get('/')
```

Basically, nock checks all the interceptors it has active until a match is found for your request (in case you have multiple nock interceptors mocking a variety of requests). So what will be logged using `.log(console.log)` is,

1. a whole url to which the request is being made.
2. a url from the interceptor
3. true or false, depending upon the match scenario.
   Hope this will help you resolve mysteries of nock :)

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: (0 , _nock.default)(...).get(...).log is not a function` when I try the above code.

Comment: @EdwardD'Souza call log() as nock(...).log()

Answer (score 4):

You can [log requests to the console](https://github.com/nock/nock#recording) using:

```js
nock.recorder.rec();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also listen to nock's [event emitters](https://github.com/nock/nock#events) to create a callback for whenever a request is intercepted.  For example:

```js
const requestCallback = () => {
    console.log('Request was called');
}
nock('https://example.org')
    .persist()
    .get('/')
    .on('request', requestCallback);
```